# Optimization data table columns vue component

Tags: vue.js, optimization, vuejs2, datatables, vue-component

I am a beginner in Vuejs, I have a project that uses VueJS 2 and BootstrapVue. I made the DataTable.vue component and use it anywhere I want, but there are should be dynamic columns with actions(by design in some tables first column with checkboxes, "+" buttons, some tables have actions like edit, duplicate, delete, or separate) and data(data may vary depending on page(courses, labs, lectures). I got a question how could I optimize it?

Now I am using the if-else condition, to show the column that I need, but there is also would be a different button(not add button, checkbox for example). I know that is hardcoding, but I want to learn how to optimize that kind of stuff. What are the best practices? (may be using index for each label(column) idk, how to realize it)

DataTable.vue

```
<template>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <td v-if="showAdd">
      </td>
      <td class = "labels" v-for="(label, labelIndex) in labels" :key="labelIndex">
        {{ label.text }}
      </td>
      <td class="labels actions" v-if="showActions">
        Action
      </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, itemIndex) in data" :key="itemIndex">
      <td v-if="showAdd">
          <b-icon icon="plus" class="add-btn" @click="$emit('add-item', item.name)">
          </b-icon>
      </td>
      <td v-for="(label, labelIndex) in labels" :key="labelIndex">
        {{ item[label.field] }}
      </td>
      <td class="actions" v-if="showActions">
        <ActionColumn :item="item"></ActionColumn>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

```
<script>

// Data and labels
import ActionColumn from "@/components/UI/ActionColumn.vue";

export default {
  name: "DataTable",
  components: {ActionColumn},
  props: {
    labels: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    data: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    showActions: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    showAdd: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

ActionColum.vue (my action buttons)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link to="/dubplicate">
      <b-icon icon="files" variant="dark"></b-icon>
    </router-link>
    <router-link to="/delete">
      <b-icon icon="trash" variant="danger"></b-icon>
    </router-link>
    <router-link to="/edit">
      <b-icon icon="pencil" variant="dark"></b-icon>
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

Labs.vue

```
<template>
        <DataTable :labels="labels" :data="data" show-actions="true"/>
</template>

<script>
// Data and labels
const labels = [
  { text: "ID", field: 'id' },
  { text: "Name", field: 'name' },
  { text: "Description", field: 'description' },
]
const data = [
  { id: 10, name: 'Lab 1', description: 'Password Cracking' },
  { id: 11, name: 'Lab 13', description: 'SIEM and MISP machine' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Lab 15', description: 'AD auditing lab' },
  { id: 34, name: 'Lab 31', description: 'Threat Hunting and Investigation' },
];
export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line vue/multi-word-component-names
  name: "Labs",
  data() {
    return {
      labels: labels,
      data: data,
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at vuejs [slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html). That's how you could have dynamic "action" column regarding the component usage you want.

Comment: here I made a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-grass-9d0u8e?file=/src/components/ComponentB.vue